# Void method to convert miles to kilometers/ kilometers to miles

Tags: java, void

Hello StackOverflow this is my first post so I apologize if this formatting is messed up. My instructions are: **Write a class named DistanceVoid that contains the void method distance as below. When called repeatedly inside a loop in the main method, this one method (by itself) should generate the exact same table as displayed by program 1 above.** I would put an image but it won't let me. Here is my code.

```
package bryant6;


public class DistanceVoid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        distance(0);
    }

    public static void distance(double dist) {

        System.out.println("  Miles  Kilometers - Kilometers  Miles");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        int counter = 0;
        int distanceCounter = 0;
        while (counter < 10) {
            counter++;
            dist++;
            distanceCounter++;
            dist = distanceCounter * 1.609;
            System.out.print(counter + " ");
            System.out.println(dist);

        }

    }
}
```

I have done a lot of research and tried taking care of this and I posted in my class forum with no replies. Any direction will help. **I need to also be able to print the Kilometers to miles within this code in the void method I am calling**. Any recommendations on how to make this code cleaner and better will also be appreciated!

Here is a link to what the outcome should be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgys3.jpg

Comment: I did not understand so well what they should do this program..

Comment: What its exactly the problem that you have?

Comment: I will type out what outcome should look like I couldn't get the image link to work

Comment: Your ouput is supposed to be an image?

Comment: I just realized when reading my own question that I need to move my loop from the void method distance to the main method. My main question is I don't know how I should go about have it print both the miles -> kilometers AND the kilometers -> miles

Comment: Just issue another print with `distanceCounter / 1.609`. I assume your course hasn't introduced you to `for` loops yet - look it up, you might find it easier than this `while`.

Comment: Here is what the outcome should look like http://imgur.com/H9HuTye I need to also be able to print out km to miles which the equation is 1 mile = 0.621 km

Comment: I wrote a simple program for you, can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know what you're writing, because I added my solution. I hope that it'll help you.

```
public class Calculator {

    private String distance(int destination, boolean isMiles) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if (destination < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            return String.format(destination + "  " +
                new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(
                        isMiles ? destination / 0.621371192 : destination / 1.609344));
        }
}
```

And usage in the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(new Calculator().distance(10, false)); // 10 km
        System.out.println(new Calculator().distance(10, true)); // 10 m
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("You pass wrong arguments to the method!");
    }
}
```

Output #1:

```
10  6.214
10  16.093
```

Next in the `for` loop you can print multiple values in a column.

```
for (int i = 0; i++ < 5;) {
    System.out.println(new Calculator().distance(i, false));
}
```

Output #2:

```
1  0.621
2  1.243
3  1.864
4  2.485
5  3.107
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, let me play around with this code a bit. I am still very new at Java. Don't go out of your way but if you could comment out your work a bit so I can understand it easier I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @CoreyBryant, ok, what do you not understand here?

Comment: @AndrewTobiko I did not know what IllegalArumentException was but I looked it up, I have also never seen try or catch.

Comment: @CoreyBryant, Here we check the correctness of the the received parameters. [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: @CoreyBryant, `destination` won't be a negative number